# Join two tables to get data on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have 2 tables

**1.Table groups**

- group_id
- group_name
- game_id

**2.Table champ_groups**

- id
- championship_id
- group_id

**group_id** is PK for Table `groups` and FK for Table `champ_groups`.
**championship_id** is unique id assigned to a championship.
and Table_champ_groups contain different groups allowed in a championship.
I want to join both the tables in such a way that I get list of **group_name** along with **group_id**  of a particular championship.
This is what I have tried till now

```
SELECT *
FROM champ_group cg 
INNER JOIN groups g
ON cg.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE cg.championship_id  = '80623809'
```

**Desired Result**

```
group_id | championship_id | group_name
1        | 80623809        | Micro-U/6
2        | 80623809        | Mini-U/8
```

How do I get the desired result ?

Comment: Could you add sample data and what do you expect as a result?

Comment: What happens when you run the query you have? How does it differ from the result you want? Right now I tend to think you only need to select the columns you want instead of selecting `*` in your query, but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is almost 100% correct. If you only need the group_name along with the group_id as a result you have only to substitute the asterisk in your select with the following:

```
SELECT g.group_name, g.group_id
FROM champ_group cg 
INNER JOIN groups g
    ON cg.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE cg.championship_id  = '1'
```

Based on your question, it is slightly unclear of what you might expect as a result as your query seems totally correct.